# Rails Action Cable Request origin not allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am trying to configure Action Cable in my api-only rails application. After a very basic set up I tried to connect to the server from my Ember application. It doesn't connect and on Rails console I see following error entries:

```
Started GET "/cable" for 172.17.0.1 at 2017-12-20 10:17:26 +0000
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 172.17.0.1 at 2017-12-20 10:17:26 Request origin not allowed: http://localhost:4200
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 172.17.0.1 at 2
```

After a quick search (followed by a compreshensive one) the solution looked simple. Add following line in config/development.rb and it should be resolved:

```
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['http://localhost:4200']
```

(note: 4200 is the port where ember server is running and the request is coming from, the rails is running on standad 3000 port). However, the problem is still there. I tried lot of things whtatever I could find on internet but the problem is still there.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you temporarily set it to all? `config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/.*/]`

Comment: I'll give it a try when I reach office, but I doubt it will help as I added multiple entries there such as localhost:3000, 0.0.0.0:3000 etc. but problem remained there. After spending hours and hours on it now I suspect it might be due to the fact that it is an API-only application.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue was with not rails, but library https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31524